# How to use grep on a variable or string?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm writing a bash script and I need to check if a file name has a number at the end (after a period) and if so get it, but I can't figure out how to use regex on a variable or string.

I was able to use `echo` in the terminal to pipe a string into grep, like this:

```
 echo "filename.txt.123" | egrep -o "\.[0-9]+$" | egrep -o "[0-9]+"
```

But I need to assign the output of this to a variable. I tried doing this:

```
 revNumber= echo "filename.txt.123" | egrep -o "\.[0-9]+$" | egrep -o "[0-9]+"
```

But that doesn't work. I tried a bunch of other things as well, but nothing was valid.

In my bash script I want to use grep on a variable and not a string, but the concept here is the same.

How can I use grep on a string or variable and then save the result into another variable?

Comment: can't backquotes solve it.. that's the syntax for getting the output of a command into a variable. `r=\`echo abc\`` echo $r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assign the output of a command to a variable, use [`$()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
revNumber=$(echo "filename.txt.123" | egrep -o "\.[0-9]+$" | egrep -o "[0-9]+")
```

If all you care about is *matching*, you might want to consider [`case`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

```
case foo in
  f*) echo starts with f
   ;;
  *) echo does not start with f
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: Good answer. I knew about the backtick/backquote form of command substitution, but I had forgotten about the `$()` form.

Comment: @Arkanon: `\`\`` is old-style; `$()` is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Why the grep and echo I/O overkill, I'd suggest using bash string processing capabilities:

```
TESTFNAME="filename.txt.283" # you can collect this from doing an ls in the target directory

# acquire last extension using a regexp, including the '.':
FEXT=$(expr "$TESTFNAME" : '.*\(\.[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*\)')

# check if length is more than just the dot, that means we've got digits:
if [  ${#FEXT} -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Gotcha!" $testFilename ${#FEXT} $FEXT # do whatever you like with the file
fi
```

The regex can be optimized and isn't perfect, but here are the basics:

- .* at the beginning will search at the end of the file.
- [[:digit::]]
  is almost the same as [0-9], but I find it more readable

Check out other **bash** string manipulation capabilities at TLDP [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Answer (score 0):

The below is another option that uses a bash regex comparison before extracting the value at the end of the string.

```
if [[ $TESTFNAME =~ \.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  VAL=$(egrep -o '[0-9]+$' <<<"$TESTFNAME")
fi
```